# mark JPA object as Transient but still return in JaxWsProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, jpa, jax-ws

I have a field marked as javax.persistence.transient in JPA bean to make JPA ignore it (otherwise throws error during JPA operations). This works fine for JPA and JAX-WS webservices return the field ok. However, if I use url and interface with JaxWsProxyFactoryBean (java calling webservice using JaxWsProxyFactoryBean) the fields marked as transient are not returned. This obviously must be becuase JaxWsProxyFactoryBean is using serialization and removing them due to @Transient.

My Question, is there a way to have JPA ignore it but still have JaxWsProxyFactoryBean return that field ?

example:

```
class House {
...
    @Transient
    // JaxWsProxyFactoryBean  clients dont return this due to @Transient
    // when this object is returned in a web service
    private Address address; 
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to have separate beans for JPA and for WS, with a service layer that maps between the two (you can use ModelMapper to faciliate the mapping).

With this pattern, you can have your JPA bean correctly model the persistence, and have a WS bean that correctly models the interaction with your clients.

Comment: I tried creating a different bean for the database but that made code really ugly, dramatically increased memory (x2) and v of bugs. Instead, I am just going to have new webservice methods and have clients call them to set these values after the original call. Not ideal but only way to handle it. (I also tried override readObject, writeObject but cxf client doesn't even call those so that didn't work either)